# error[E0599]: no method named `gen` found for type `&mut G` in the current scope

Tags: rust, quickcheck

I'm trying to use the [quickcheck crate](https://docs.rs/quickcheck/0.8.5/quickcheck/index.html).

I've implemented `Arbitrary` for the struct `Point {x: u32, y: u32}`

```
impl Arbitrary for Point {
    fn arbitrary<G: Gen>(g: &mut G) -> Point {
        let x = g.gen::<u32>();
        let y = g.gen::<u32>();

        Point { x, y }
    }
}
```

and the compiler says:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `gen` found for type `&mut G` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:61:23
   |
61 |             let x = g.gen::<u32>();
   |                       ^^^
   |
   = note: the method `gen` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `&mut G : rand::Rng`
           `G : rand::Rng`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
   = note: the following trait is implemented but not in scope, perhaps add a `use` for it:
           `use rand::Rng;`
```

But I do have `use rand:Rng;` in the test module, and `rand` as a dev-dependency in my Cargo.toml.

I also have `use quickcheck::{quickcheck, Arbitrary, Gen};` in the module.

What am I missing in order to create arbitrary generators?

--- EDIT ---
If you want to run https://gist.github.com/russelldb/49b96ca2e23dfab8a0f03090144735e4 for me it reproduces the issue.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], because your code looks good to me, so the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Doesn't a `use rand::Rng;` at the top solve the problem ?

Comment: I have a use rand::Rng;. I will try and post a MRE.

Comment: There is a minimal (small?) repro ex here https://gist.github.com/russelldb/49b96ca2e23dfab8a0f03090144735e4 . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @russelldb please include that into this question, instead of using github. Please [edit] your question :)

Comment: Yeah, I can see that the cause is the same thing (versions) but the error message is different. For example, now that I KNOW the cause (versions of crates in deps) is common I know this is the same issue, but without knowing that, it is not at all clear from the error messages. If I click on "this issue is the same" button, will this issue vanish? Because I think that the title is nicely searchable and specific too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with quickcheck. [Quickcheck uses rand version 0.6.5](https://github.com/BurntSushi/quickcheck/blob/b3e50a5e7c85e19538cf8612d9fd6da32c588930/Cargo.toml#L30), whereas the newest version of [rand is 0.7.0](https://crates.io/crates/rand).

Because traits of different version aren't compatible rustc gives you this error.

To resolve it, declare rand in the version 0.6.5 as dependecy and it will work.

Comment: That's great, and that solves it, many thanks. So if quickcheck depends on rand, why do I need to declare a dependency on it at all?